# Unable to start Virtualbox machine on Kubuntu 22.04 / VM session was aborted

Tags: kubuntu, virtualbox

I am having issues with Virutalbox 6.1.34 on kubuntu 22.04. Many Virtual machines that used to work don't now.
I get this kind of error:

[image].

I search a bit on google, but there is not simple fix. It seems it has something to do with Extensionpack. I have uninstall and re-install multiple times, but this don't seems to solve the issue.

The complete log file looks like this:

```
00:00:01.043985 VirtualBox VM 6.1.34_Ubuntu r150636 linux.amd64 (May 13 2022 07:34:48) release log
00:00:01.043985 Log opened 2022-09-11T03:43:14.596308000Z
00:00:01.043985 Build Type: release
00:00:01.043985 OS Product: Linux
00:00:01.043985 OS Release: 5.15.0-47-generic
00:00:01.043985 OS Version: #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022
00:00:01.043985 DMI Product Name: Precision T1650
00:00:01.043985 DMI Product Version: 01
00:00:01.043985 Firmware type: UEFI
00:00:01.043985 Secure Boot: Disabled
00:00:01.043985 Host RAM: 31991MB (31.2GB) total, 29800MB (29.1GB) available
00:00:01.043985 Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM
00:00:01.043985 Process ID: 4592
00:00:01.043985 Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC (OSE)
00:00:01.105530 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:01.105568   VNC (Version: 6.1.34 r150636; VRDE Module: VBoxVNC)
00:00:01.105578   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (Version: 6.1.38 r153438; VRDE Module: VBoxVRDP)
00:00:01.107089 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:01.107269 Qt version: 5.15.3
00:00:01.107278 X11 Window Manager code: 3
00:00:01.112073 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:01.113311 X Server details: vendor: The X.Org Foundation, release: 12101003, protocol version: 11.0, display string: :0
00:00:01.113349 Using XKB for keycode to scan code conversion
00:00:01.120712 SUP: seg #0: R   0x00000000 LB 0x0004d000
00:00:01.120753 SUP: seg #1: R X 0x0004d000 LB 0x0011c000
00:00:01.120758 SUP: seg #2: R   0x00169000 LB 0x00060000
00:00:01.120762 SUP: seg #3: RW  0x001c9000 LB 0x000350a8
00:00:01.121378 GUI: UIDesktopWidgetWatchdog::sltHandleHostScreenAvailableGeometryCalculated: Screen 0 work area is actually resized to: 0x0 x 1920x1044
00:00:01.121963 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (/usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0) at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - ModuleInit at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ModuleTerm at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:01.121978 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and VMMR0EntryFast at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:01.124038 Guest OS type: 'Windows7_64'
00:00:01.125916 GUI: UIDesktopWidgetWatchdog::sltHandleHostScreenAvailableGeometryCalculated: Screen 1 work area is actually resized to: 1920x0 x 1920x1036
00:00:01.130766 fHMForced=true - No raw-mode support in this build!
00:00:01.139195 File system of '/media/parfait/2TBSTORE/vms/New group/w_10/Snapshots' (snapshots) is unknown
00:00:01.139216 File system of '/media/parfait/2TBSTORE/vms/New group/w_10/w_10.vdi' is ext4
00:00:01.141341 File system of '/home/parfait/Downloads/iso/2022-09-04/Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso' (DVD) is ext4
00:00:01.143991 GUI: Machine-window #0 activated
00:00:01.144039 GUI: Machine-view #0 focused, reason=3
00:00:01.165011 Shared Clipboard: Service loaded
00:00:01.165038 Shared Clipboard: Mode: Off
00:00:01.165080 Shared Clipboard: Service running in normal mode
00:00:01.166326 Drag and drop service loaded
00:00:01.166335 Drag and drop mode: Off
00:00:01.168861 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
...
...
...


00:00:01.169171 
00:00:01.169172 [/Devices/hda/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:01.169174   VmName <string>  = "w_10" (cb=5)
00:00:01.169174 
00:00:01.169175 [/Devices/hda/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169176   DriverName    <string>  = "PulseAudio" (cb=11)
00:00:01.169177   InputEnabled  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169178   OutputEnabled <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169179 
00:00:01.169179 [/Devices/hda/0/LUN#1/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169181   Driver <string>  = "AUDIO" (cb=6)
00:00:01.169181 
00:00:01.169182 [/Devices/hda/0/LUN#2/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169183   Driver <string>  = "AUDIO" (cb=6)
00:00:01.169183 
00:00:01.169184 [/Devices/i8254/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169185 
00:00:01.169185 [/Devices/i8254/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169186 
00:00:01.169187 [/Devices/i8254/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169188 
00:00:01.169188 [/Devices/i8259/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169189 
00:00:01.169190 [/Devices/i8259/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169191   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169192 
00:00:01.169193 [/Devices/i8259/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169194 
00:00:01.169194 [/Devices/ioapic/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169196 
00:00:01.169196 [/Devices/ioapic/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169198   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169198 
00:00:01.169199 [/Devices/ioapic/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169200   NumCPUs <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169201 
00:00:01.169201 [/Devices/mc146818/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169203 
00:00:01.169203 [/Devices/mc146818/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169204 
00:00:01.169205 [/Devices/mc146818/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169206   UseUTC <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169207 
00:00:01.169207 [/Devices/parallel/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169208 
00:00:01.169209 [/Devices/pcarch/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169210 
00:00:01.169210 [/Devices/pcarch/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169211   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169212 
00:00:01.169213 [/Devices/pcarch/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169214 
00:00:01.169214 [/Devices/pcbios/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169215 
00:00:01.169216 [/Devices/pcbios/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169217   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169218 
00:00:01.169218 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169220   APIC               <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169221   BootDevice0        <string>  = "FLOPPY" (cb=7)
00:00:01.169222   BootDevice1        <string>  = "DVD" (cb=4)
00:00:01.169222   BootDevice2        <string>  = "IDE" (cb=4)
00:00:01.169223   BootDevice3        <string>  = "NONE" (cb=5)
00:00:01.169224   FloppyDevice       <string>  = "i82078" (cb=7)
00:00:01.169225   HardDiskDevice     <string>  = "piix3ide" (cb=9)
00:00:01.169226   IOAPIC             <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169227   LanBootRom         <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/PXE-Intel.rom" (cb=85)
00:00:01.169228   McfgBase           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169229   McfgLength         <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169230   NumCPUs            <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169231   PXEDebug           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169232   SataHardDiskDevice <string>  = "ahci" (cb=5)
00:00:01.169233   SataLUN1           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169234   UUID               <bytes>   = "f9 ee 86 19 b3 69 ab 4a a5 14 70 a7 46 d6 ff 0d" (cb=16)
00:00:01.169237   UuidLe             <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169238 
00:00:01.169238 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/NetBoot/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169240 
00:00:01.169240 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/NetBoot/0/] (level 6)
00:00:01.169242   NIC           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169243   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169244   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:01.169245   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169246 
00:00:01.169247 [/Devices/pci/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169248 
00:00:01.169248 [/Devices/pci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169250   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169251 
00:00:01.169251 [/Devices/pci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169253   IOAPIC <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169254 
00:00:01.169254 [/Devices/pcibridge/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169255 
00:00:01.169255 [/Devices/pckbd/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169257 
00:00:01.169257 [/Devices/pckbd/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169258   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169259 
00:00:01.169259 [/Devices/pckbd/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169260 
00:00:01.169261 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169262   Driver <string>  = "KeyboardQueue" (cb=14)
00:00:01.169263 
00:00:01.169263 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169265   Driver <string>  = "MainKeyboard" (cb=13)
00:00:01.169266 
00:00:01.169266 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:01.169268   Object <integer> = 0x00005579f7f3c530 (93 982 339 351 856)
00:00:01.169270 
00:00:01.169270 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169271   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000040 (64)
00:00:01.169272 
00:00:01.169273 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169274   Driver <string>  = "MouseQueue" (cb=11)
00:00:01.169275 
00:00:01.169275 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169277   Driver <string>  = "MainMouse" (cb=10)
00:00:01.169278 
00:00:01.169278 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:01.169280   Object <integer> = 0x00007f8b8c00fa30 (140 237 326 055 984)
00:00:01.169281 
00:00:01.169282 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169284   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000080 (128)
00:00:01.169285 
00:00:01.169285 [/Devices/pcnet/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169286 
00:00:01.169287 [/Devices/serial/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169288 
00:00:01.169288 [/Devices/usb-ehci/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169289 
00:00:01.169290 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169291   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169293   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x000000000000000b (11)
00:00:01.169294   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169294   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169295 
00:00:01.169296 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169297 
00:00:01.169297 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169299   Driver <string>  = "VUSBRootHub" (cb=12)
00:00:01.169299 
00:00:01.169300 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169301 
00:00:01.169301 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169303   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:01.169303 
00:00:01.169304 [/Devices/usb-ehci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169306   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169307   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169308   papLeds <integer> = 0x00007f8b8c002758 (140 237 326 002 008)
00:00:01.169309 
00:00:01.169309 [/Devices/usb-ohci/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169311 
00:00:01.169311 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169312   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169313   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000006 (6)
00:00:01.169315   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169316   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169317 
00:00:01.169317 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169318 
00:00:01.169318 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169320   Driver <string>  = "VUSBRootHub" (cb=12)
00:00:01.169321 
00:00:01.169321 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169322 
00:00:01.169323 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169324   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:01.169325 
00:00:01.169325 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169327   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169328   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169329   papLeds <integer> = 0x00007f8b8c002750 (140 237 326 002 000)
00:00:01.169330 
00:00:01.169330 [/Devices/vga/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169332 
00:00:01.169332 [/Devices/vga/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169334   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169335   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:01.169336   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169337   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169337 
00:00:01.169338 [/Devices/vga/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169342   3DEnabled        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169343   CustomVideoModes <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169344   FadeIn           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169345   FadeOut          <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169346   HeightReduction  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169348   LogoFile         <string>  = "" (cb=1)
00:00:01.169349   LogoTime         <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169350   MonitorCount     <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169351   ShowBootMenu     <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:01.169352   VMSVGA3dEnabled  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169353   VMSVGAEnabled    <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169354   VRamSize         <integer> = 0x0000000001b00000 (28 311 552, 27 MB)
00:00:01.169356 
00:00:01.169356 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169357   Driver <string>  = "MainDisplay" (cb=12)
00:00:01.169358 
00:00:01.169358 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169359   Object <integer> = 0x00007f8b8c004090 (140 237 326 008 464)
00:00:01.169361 
00:00:01.169361 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169362   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:01.169363 
00:00:01.169363 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169365   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169365   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169366   papLeds <integer> = 0x00007f8b8c002760 (140 237 326 002 016)
00:00:01.169367 
00:00:01.169368 [/Devices/virtio-net/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169369 
00:00:01.169369 [/EM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169370   TripleFaultReset <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169370 
00:00:01.169371 [/GIM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169372   Provider <string>  = "HyperV" (cb=7)
00:00:01.169372 
00:00:01.169373 [/HM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169374   64bitEnabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169375   EnableLargePages   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169376   EnableNestedPaging <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169377   EnableUX           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169378   EnableVPID         <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169379   Exclusive          <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169380   HMForced           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169381   IBPBOnVMEntry      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169382   IBPBOnVMExit       <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169383   L1DFlushOnSched    <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169384   L1DFlushOnVMEntry  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169385   MDSClearOnSched    <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169386   MDSClearOnVMEntry  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169387   SpecCtrlByHost     <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169388   UseNEMInstead      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169389 
00:00:01.169390 [/MM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169391   CanUseLargerHeap <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169392 
00:00:01.169392 [/NEM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169393   Allow64BitGuests <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:01.169394 
00:00:01.169394 [/PDM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169396 
00:00:01.169396 [/PDM/AsyncCompletion/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169397 
00:00:01.169398 [/PDM/AsyncCompletion/File/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169399 
00:00:01.169400 [/PDM/AsyncCompletion/File/BwGroups/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169401 
00:00:01.169402 [/PDM/BlkCache/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169403   CacheSize <integer> = 0x0000000000500000 (5 242 880, 5 MB)
00:00:01.169405 
00:00:01.169405 [/PDM/Devices/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169406 
00:00:01.169406 [/PDM/Devices/VBoxEhci/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169408   Path         <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxEhciR3.so" (cb=97)
00:00:01.169409   R0SearchPath <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64" (cb=83)
00:00:01.169410 
00:00:01.169411 [/PDM/Devices/VBoxNvme/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169412   Path         <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxNvmeR3.so" (cb=97)
00:00:01.169413   R0SearchPath <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64" (cb=83)
00:00:01.169414 
00:00:01.169414 [/PDM/Drivers/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169415 
00:00:01.169416 [/PDM/Drivers/DrvHostWebcam/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169417   Path <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxHostWebcam.so" (cb=101)
00:00:01.169418 
00:00:01.169418 [/PDM/Drivers/VBoxC/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169420   Path <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/components/VBoxC" (cb=37)
00:00:01.169420 
00:00:01.169421 [/PDM/NetworkShaper/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169422 
00:00:01.169422 [/PDM/NetworkShaper/BwGroups/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169424 
00:00:01.169424 [/PDM/USB/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169425 
00:00:01.169426 [/PDM/USB/VBoxUsbCardReader/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169427   Path <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxUsbCardReaderR3.so" (cb=106)
00:00:01.169428 
00:00:01.169429 [/PDM/USB/VBoxUsbWebcam/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169430   Path <string>  = "/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxUsbWebcamR3.so" (cb=102)
00:00:01.169432 
00:00:01.169432 [/TM/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169433   UTCOffset <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:01.169435 
00:00:01.169435 [/USB/] (level 1)
00:00:01.169436 
00:00:01.169437 [/USB/HidMouse/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169439 
00:00:01.169439 [/USB/HidMouse/0/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169440 
00:00:01.169441 [/USB/HidMouse/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169443   Mode <string>  = "absolute" (cb=9)
00:00:01.169443 
00:00:01.169444 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:01.169445   Driver <string>  = "MouseQueue" (cb=11)
00:00:01.169445 
00:00:01.169446 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169447   Driver <string>  = "MainMouse" (cb=10)
00:00:01.169448 
00:00:01.169448 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:01.169450   Object <integer> = 0x00007f8b8c00fa30 (140 237 326 055 984)
00:00:01.169451 
00:00:01.169452 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:01.169453   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000080 (128)
00:00:01.169454 
00:00:01.169454 [/USB/USBProxy/] (level 2)
00:00:01.169455 
00:00:01.169456 [/USB/USBProxy/GlobalConfig/] (level 3)
00:00:01.169457 
00:00:01.169457 ********************* End of CFGM dump **********************
00:00:01.170339 HM: HMR3Init: VT-x w/ nested paging and unrestricted guest execution hw support
00:00:01.170410 MM: cbHyperHeap=0x200000 (2097152)
00:00:01.171759 CPUM: fXStateHostMask=0x7; initial: 0x7; host XCR0=0x7
00:00:01.172620 CPUM: Matched host CPU INTEL 0x6/0x3a/0x9 Intel_Core7_IvyBridge with CPU DB entry 'Intel Core i5-3570' (INTEL 0x6/0x3a/0x9 Intel_Core7_IvyBridge)
00:00:01.173152 CPUM: MXCSR_MASK=0xffff (host: 0xffff)
00:00:01.173167 CPUM: Microcode revision 0x00000021
00:00:01.173179 CPUM: MSR/CPUID reconciliation insert: 0x0000010b IA32_FLUSH_CMD
00:00:01.174004 PGM: Host paging mode: AMD64+PGE+NX
00:00:01.174017 PGM: PGMPool: cMaxPages=4352 (u64MaxPages=4136)
00:00:01.174023 PGM: pgmR3PoolInit: cMaxPages=0x1100 cMaxUsers=0x2200 cMaxPhysExts=0x2000 fCacheEnable=true 
00:00:01.175312 PGM: /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count = 65530 (rc2=VWRN_TRAILING_CHARS); cGuessNeeded=16384
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - u32Mode=3 (Invariant) u32UpdateHz=62 u32UpdateIntervalNS=16000000 enmUseTscDelta=2 (Practically Zero) fGetGipCpu=0x1b cCpus=8
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - u64CpuHz=3 392 284 703 (0xca32281f)  SUPGetCpuHzFromGip => 3 392 284 703
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x0 idCpu=0x0 idApic=0x0 iGipCpu=0x7 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284648(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x1 idCpu=0x1 idApic=0x2 iGipCpu=0x5 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284464(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x2 idCpu=0x2 idApic=0x4 iGipCpu=0x0 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284703(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x3 idCpu=0x3 idApic=0x6 iGipCpu=0x4 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284418(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x4 idCpu=0x4 idApic=0x1 iGipCpu=0x6 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284596(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x5 idCpu=0x5 idApic=0x3 iGipCpu=0x2 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284506(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x6 idCpu=0x6 idApic=0x5 iGipCpu=0x1 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392266934(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: GIP - CPU: iCpuSet=0x7 idCpu=0x7 idApic=0x7 iGipCpu=0x3 i64TSCDelta=0 enmState=3 u64CpuHz=3392284286(*) cErrors=0
00:00:01.187988 TM: cTSCTicksPerSecond=3 392 284 703 (0xca32281f) enmTSCMode=3 (Dynamic)
00:00:01.187988 TM: TSCTiedToExecution=false TSCNotTiedToHalt=false
00:00:01.192260 EMR3Init: fIemExecutesAll=false fGuruOnTripleFault=true 
00:00:01.192343 IEM: TargetCpu=CURRENT, Microarch=Intel_Core7_IvyBridge
00:00:01.192827 GIM: Using provider 'HyperV' (Implementation version: 0)
00:00:01.192833 GIM: HyperV: Reporting vendor as 'VBoxVBoxVBox'
00:00:01.192838 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled Hypervisor Present bit
00:00:01.252069 AIOMgr: Default manager type is 'Async'
00:00:01.252144 AIOMgr: Default file backend is 'NonBuffered'
00:00:01.252524 BlkCache: Cache successfully initialized. Cache size is 5242880 bytes
00:00:01.252533 BlkCache: Cache commit interval is 10000 ms
00:00:01.252537 BlkCache: Cache commit threshold is 2621440 bytes
00:00:01.261510 PcBios: [SMP] BIOS with 1 CPUs
00:00:01.262383 PcBios: Using the 386+ BIOS image.
00:00:01.263809 PcBios: MPS table at 000e1300
00:00:01.264458 PcBios: Using LAN ROM '/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/PXE-Intel.rom' with a size of 0xc000 bytes
00:00:01.264838 PcBios: fCheckShutdownStatusForSoftReset=true   fClearShutdownStatusOnHardReset=true 
00:00:01.266641 SUP: seg #0: R   0x00000000 LB 0x00009000
00:00:01.266647 SUP: seg #1: R X 0x00009000 LB 0x00020000
00:00:01.266650 SUP: seg #2: R   0x00029000 LB 0x0000c000
00:00:01.266652 SUP: seg #3: RW  0x00035000 LB 0x000074d8
00:00:01.266731 SUP: Loaded VBoxDDR0.r0 (/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxDDR0.r0) at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - ModuleInit at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ModuleTerm at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:01.267386 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled xAPIC
00:00:01.267565 IOAPIC: Using implementation 2.0! Chipset type ICH9
00:00:01.267622 PIT: mode=3 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:01.267759 VMMDev: cbDefaultBudget: 524 141 120 (1f3dc240)
00:00:01.270578 Shared Folders service loaded
00:00:01.272127 Guest Control service loaded
00:00:01.282498 VGA: Using the 386+ BIOS image.
00:00:01.284924 VD: VDInit finished with VINF_SUCCESS
00:00:01.285171 DrvVD: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:01.285176 DrvVD: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:01.287096 AIOMgr: Endpoint for file '/media/parfait/2TBSTORE/vms/New group/w_10/w_10.vdi' (flags 000c0723) created successfully
00:00:01.289691 VD: Opening the disk took 2884002 ns
00:00:01.289758 AHCI: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 314572800
00:00:01.290449 DrvVD: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:01.290457 DrvVD: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:01.292327 AIOMgr: Endpoint for file '/home/parfait/Downloads/iso/2022-09-04/Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso' (flags 000c0781) created successfully
00:00:01.292344 VD: Opening the disk took 148623 ns
00:00:01.292427 AHCI: LUN#1: CD/DVD
00:00:01.292686 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:01.292695 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:01.293143 E1000#0: Chip=82540EM LinkUpDelay=3000ms EthernetCRC=on GSO=enabled Itr=disabled ItrRx=enabled TID=disabled R0=enabled RC=disabled
00:00:01.300448 NAT: Guest address guess set to 10.0.2.15 by initialization
00:00:01.300543 NAT: resolv.conf: nameserver 127.0.0.53
00:00:01.300549 NAT: resolv.conf: ignoring "options edns0 trust-ad"
00:00:01.300559 NAT: DNS server 127.0.0.53 registration detected, switching to the DNS proxy
00:00:01.300563 NAT: Adding domain name .
00:00:01.300565 NAT: DNS#0: 127.0.0.53
00:00:01.302298 Audio: Initializing PulseAudio driver
00:00:01.303931 PulseAudio: Using version 15.99.0
00:00:01.305652 PulseAudio: Retrieving server information ...
00:00:01.306133 Audio: Found 3 devices for driver 'PulseAudio'
00:00:01.306139 Audio: Device 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo':
00:00:01.306140 Audio:   ID              = alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
00:00:01.306140 Audio:   Usage           = output
00:00:01.306140 Audio:   Flags           = DEFAULT_OUT
00:00:01.306141 Audio:   Input channels  = 0
00:00:01.306141 Audio:   Output channels = 2
00:00:01.306144 Audio: Device 'Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo':
00:00:01.306144 Audio:   ID              = alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
00:00:01.306144 Audio:   Usage           = input
00:00:01.306145 Audio:   Flags           = NONE
00:00:01.306145 Audio:   Input channels  = 2
00:00:01.306145 Audio:   Output channels = 0
00:00:01.306155 Audio: Device 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo':
00:00:01.306156 Audio:   ID              = alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
00:00:01.306156 Audio:   Usage           = input
00:00:01.306156 Audio:   Flags           = DEFAULT_IN
00:00:01.306156 Audio:   Input channels  = 2
00:00:01.306157 Audio:   Output channels = 0
00:00:01.306213 HDA: Codec reset
00:00:01.306219 HDA: Reset
00:00:01.306992 SUP: seg #0: R X 0x00000000 LB 0x00001000
00:00:01.307000 SUP: seg #1: R X 0x00001000 LB 0x00002000
00:00:01.307003 SUP: seg #2: R   0x00003000 LB 0x00101000
00:00:01.307006 SUP: seg #3: RW  0x00104000 LB 0x00000820
00:00:01.307356 SUP: Loaded VBoxEhciR0.r0 (/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxEhciR0.r0) at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - ModuleInit at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ModuleTerm at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Any one has an idea how to fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 October2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: You mix both *kinetic* (22.10) and 22.04 (*jammy*) in your details; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is a *released* product thus on-topic here, but Ubuntu *kinetic* is not.